# Some classes in VB.NET are not visible

Tags: windows-phone

Please help me I am facing this problem where some of my applications classes are not visible or accessable in VB.NET while it is accessable in C# ,For example see this picture :

[image: Visual VB and Visual C# showing same line of code but VB can not recognize the class]

I tried using same namespace in C# and VB and found it is not recognizable in VB ,Why?

ofcourse all assemblies are added and namespaces are imported correctly.

I think this problem is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310817/microsoft-visualbasic-namespace-in-wp8)

and It just got started when I started WP development,I think it is not present in windows development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the solution but I rebuilt the whole WP project and the problem resolved and I can access the classes normally

Actually this is the [solution](http://blog.themagicsoftware.com/2012/03/in-shelltile-tiletofind-shelltile-activetiles-first-first-doesnt-get-recognized-problem.html)

These types of errors are sooooo nasty.